# AngularJs - Testing REST API with api-easy

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using api-easy to test my REST api. As i run the test with following command, i get error `ECONNREFUSED`.

```
vows test.js
```

test.js

```
'use strict';

var APIeasy = require('api-easy'),
    http = require('http'),
    assert = require('assert');

var suite = APIeasy.describe('/api/states');

suite.discuss('When using your awesome API')
    .discuss('and your awesome resource')
    .use('localhost', 9000)
    .setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .get('/api/states')
    .expect(200, { ok: true })
    .export(module);
```

error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying co connect to an non-existing host e.g. not running localhost server.

If you get ECONNREFUSED that indicates a wrong hostname:port, you can try a simple node call in the REPL

$ node

> var http = require('http');
>   http.get({hostname:'localhost',port:3500}, function(response) {
>   ... console.log(response);
>   });

if the localhost isn't running on that port you get:

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)`

if it is running (like $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3500) then you see the log of the response object. So wrapped up, you are calling a wrong hostname:port

Comment: Just running the project ... done the thing for me...!